# Providing documentation with Node/JS REST APIs

Tags: node.js, swagger, apiblueprint, raml

I'm looking to build a REST API using Node and Express and I'd like to provide documentation with it.  I don't want to craft this by hand and it appears that there are solutions available in the forms of Swagger, RAML and Api Blueprint/Apiary.

What I'd really like is to have the documentation auto-generate from the API code as is possible in .NET land with Swashbuckle or the Microsoft provided solution but they're made possible by strong typing and reflection.

For the JS world it seems like the correct option is to use the Swagger/RAML/Api Blueprint markup to define the API and then generate the documentation and scaffold the server from that.  The former seems straightforward but I'm less sure about the latter.  What I've seen of the server code generation for all of these options seem very limited.  There needs to be some way to separate the auto-generated code from the manual code so that the definition can be updated easily and I've seen no sign or discussion on that.  It doesn't seem like an insurmountable problem (I'm much more familiar with .NET than JS so I could easily be missing something) and there is mention of this issue and solutions being worked on in a [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534792/good-rest-code-generation-and-documentation-tool) from over a year ago.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing/misunderstanding anything and if any solution for the above problem exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with APIs and dynamic languages is that the accent is on verification instead of code generation.

For example, if using a compiled language I generate artifacts from the API spec and use that to enforce correctness. Round tripping is supported via the generation of interfaces instead of concrete classes.

With a dynamic language, the spec is used at test time to guarantee that both all the defined API is test covered and that the responses are conform to the spec (I tend to not validate requests because of Postel's law, but it is possible too).

Answer (score 4):

the initial version of [swagger-node-express](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/tree/v2.1.2) did just this--you would define some metadata from the routes, models, etc., and the documentation would auto-generate from it.  Given how dynamic javascript is, this became a bit cumbersome for many to use, as it required you to keep the metadata up-to-date against the models in a somewhat decoupled manner.

Fast forward and the latest [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) project takes an alternative approach which can be considered in-line with "generating documentation from code" in a sense.  In this project (and [swagger-inflector](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-inflector) for java, and [connexion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion) for python) take the approach that the swagger specification *is* the DSL for the api, and the routing logic is handled by what is defined in the swagger document.  From there, you simply implement the controllers.

If you treat the swagger specification "like code" then this is a very efficient way to go--the documentation can literally never be out of date, since it is used to construct all routes, validate all input variables, and connect the API to your business layer.

While true code generation, such as what is available from the [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) project can be extremely effective, it does require some clever integration with your code *after* you initially construct the server.  That consideration is completely removed from the workflow with the three projects above.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful.  If Stack Overflow allowed accepting multiple answers I would have marked this as an answer too.